# Needed help why background image doesn't show up on the div?

Tags: html, css

**HELP**
I dont know really what to do, I did review everything on the W3 schools website about CSS and HTML but nothing works.
File paths are correct but the background of that div  class = "mainBanner" is not functioning.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    * {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .mainBanner {  
    background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 700px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <div class="container mainBanner">
    <h1>Welcome to The Travellers Website</h1>
    <h4>You're all in one solution for perfect travels. Make memories and take          step across 
    islands you've never seen before.</h4>
    </div>
    </html>

<!--Is the background image covered by the * selector when the bg color is applied? This imgae from the .mainBanner class doesnt load even the file is correct-->
```

Comment: Hmm. I have tried the same thing but the image is properly showing. Try to remove the **_/_** before starting the url of the image. I have added the image from my directory and the image is showing properly.

Comment: tried , still doesnt work, its relaly weird, stuck on it for 30mins

Comment: Are you sure the image is **_jpg_** and not **_jpeg_** or any other extension?

Comment: I'm so stuck on it, tried transferring the directory, still not working;

Comment: yeah, its a jpg file and its path was relative and even suggested by vscode

Comment: If you are certain the file path is correct, use `background-size:100% 100%` or remove the `-image` and keep it as `background: url(...)

Comment: Is the background-color black as you have said in the CSS?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page using inspector tool? Is the path shows correct there?

Comment: its the whole page that is under the black background, but i just wanted that the div mainBanner to have the image under the text in the mainBanner. BTW i tried what you mentioned, no effect. tried removing the * css bgcolor:black; seems like the image doesnt render on the webpage

Comment: background.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND its is not found but weird though because it has the same path with my logo, and my logo works fine

Comment: Can you try removing the the first slash of the URL? (`/images` to `images`)

Comment: tried it, no effect

Comment: Try to add height and width to the image and then see if it works.

Comment: it works when written in this way: background: url(C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Webapp%20Version2/images/background.jpg);

Comment: Have you tried this `..images/background.jpg` ?

Comment: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Have you tried the one @soban recommended? If that also didn't work then you can try hovering over the file path in the inspector tool. That will give you the full wrong path of the file it is targeting, by which you can see where the problem is.

Comment: its the file path path that is messing up the whole rendering of the  image, its always not found whenever i use the either the /images  or images

Comment: im so sorry by the way for this nonesense question, im just too new i guess with css,

Comment: I am also kind of new so.. try to add background-size and debug the path on the inspector tool. Let us know if that works.

Comment: its the path that messes up, i fix it using the original pathe from the C: drive to the main folder

Comment: after I added teh bootstrap , its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the image is in the correct location, you are likely receiving issues as you haven't set a height/width of the image itself. You can do this by using `background-size`

```css
 * {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .mainBanner {  
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/7a4DOBA.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 700px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <div class="container mainBanner">
    <h1>Welcome to The Travellers Website</h1>
    <h4>You're all in one solution for perfect travels. Make memories and take          step across 
    islands you've never seen before.</h4>
    </div>
    </html>

<!--Is the background image covered by the * selector when the bg color is applied? This imgae from the .mainBanner class doesnt load even the file is correct-->
```

> Is the background image covered by the * selector when the bg color is applied? This imgae from the .mainBanner class doesnt load even the file is correct

As `.mainBanner` is more specific than `*`, css specified under the `.mainBanner` will take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(/images/background.jpg) center no-repeat ;
```

Comment: is this considering that the css file is not on the same folder as the images folder?

Comment: my file tree webapp 1.images>background.jpg     2.css>style.css      3.index.html

Comment: No, you need to add the correct path of the img. If the image is imgs folder for example.  And the image name is sea.jpg.  Then the path for url will be. Url(imgs/sea.jpg) . I will suggest you to use vscode

Comment: you included a / before images . check it out